# Need help understanding a short python code

Tags: python

I want to emphasis that this is not a ask for completing my homework or job: I am studying the LZW algorithm for gif file compression by reading someone's code on [github](https://github.com/j-s-n/mazes/blob/master/python2/GIF_maze.py), and got confused by a code block here:

```
class DataBlock(object):

    def __init__ (self):
        self.bitstream = bytearray()
        self.pos = 0

    def encode_bits (self, num, size):
        """
        Given a number *num* and a length in bits *size*, encode *num* 
        as a *size* length bitstring at the current position in the bitstream.
        """
        string = bin(num)[2:]
        string = '0'*(size - len(string)) + string
        for digit in reversed(string):
            if len(self.bitstream) * 8 <= self.pos:
                self.bitstream.append(0)
            if digit == '1':
                self.bitstream[-1] |= 1 << self.pos % 8
            self.pos += 1
```

What I cannot understand is the `for` loop in the function `encode_bits()`:

```
for digit in reversed(string):
    if len(self.bitstream) * 8 <= self.pos:
        self.bitstream.append(0)
    if digit == '1':
        self.bitstream[-1] |= 1 << self.pos % 8
    self.pos += 1
```

Here is my guess (depend on his comment):

The function `encode_bits()` will turn an input integer `num` into a binary string of length `size` (padding zeroes at left if needed) and reverse the string, and append the digits to `bitstream` one by one. Hence
suppose `s=DataBlock()`, then `s.encode_bits(3, 3)` would firstly turn 3 into `011` (padding a zero at left to make it length 3) and reverse it to `110`, and then append `110` to `self.bitstream`, hence the result should be `bytearray('110').` But as I run the code the result gives `bytearray(b'\x03')`, not as expected. Further more, `\x03` is one byte, not 3 bits, conflicts with his comment, I cannot understand why?

I forgot to add that his code runs and gives correct output hence there's something wrong in my understanding.

Comment: It fills bits from the right into the last byte of the bitstream.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Do you mean the code only changes the  bits in the last byte of the bitstream? but the first `if` in the `for` loop would append a 0(a byte) ...

Comment: It only appends a 0 byte if the length of self.bitstream (in bits) is less than self.pos - this is how self.bitstream grows, one byte at a time, only as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at it this way:

- You will be given a `bytearray` object (call it `x` for the moment).
- How many bytes are in the object?  (Obviously, it's just `len(x)`.)
- How many *bits* are in the object?  (This is an exercise; please calculate the answer.)

Once you've done that, suppose we start with no (zero) bytes in `x`, i.e., `x` is a `bytearray(b'')`.  How many *bytes* do we need to add (`x.append(...)`) in order to store three *bits*?  What if we want to store eight bits?  What if we want to store ten bits?

Again, these are exercises.  Calculate the answers and you should be enlightened.

(Incidentally, this technique, of compressing some number of sub-objects into some larger space, is called *packing*.  In mathematics the problem is [generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems), while in computers it is [often more limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand it now